# How to create a file using execl command in c

Tags: c, unix, process, os.execl

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#define MAXLINIE 100


main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (fork()==0){

        execl("/bin/> temporar.txt", "/bin/> temporar.txt", ">temporar.txt", NULL);

    }
}
```

Basically, what I am trying to do is creating a file using a process in unix, here is my code, but for some reason it does not work, I do not really understand the `execl` command and why the first two parameters have to be the same: `execl("/bin/ls", "/bin/ls", "-l", NULL);` this is working well, could someone help me ?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: What is the idea behind `"/bin/> temporar.txt"`?

Comment: The last parameter shall be `(char *) NULL`, not `NULL`.

Comment: All that parameters will be passed as variardic arguments, that have `void*` type. Anyway, C accepts some kind of implicit conversion, so `NULL` is OK even for `char*`.

Comment: @Ioentar: Verbatim from `man execl`: `The list of arguments must be terminated by a NULL pointer, and, since these are variadic functions, this pointer must be cast (char *) NULL.`

Comment: You're right. That is written in `man execl`, that it should be idealogicaly. But this is not a problem for C. Even more no one casts `(char*)NULL` even execl implementation. If you compile `execl(..., NULL)` with maximum level of warning enabled you will not get any warning regarding to implicit cast to `char*`.

Comment: 1st parameter to `execl` is the name of the program and then you start arguments to the program as subsequent arguments... The argv[0] to any C program is the name of the program itself. Hence the first two arguments are the same...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first search [whereis](http://linux.about.com/library/cmd/blcmdl1_whereis.htm) is [touch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Touch_%28Unix%29):

```
~$ whereis touch
touch: /bin/touch /usr/bin/touch /usr/bin/X11/touch
```

use: [int execl(const char *path, const char *arg, ...);](http://man.yolinux.com/cgi-bin/man2html?cgi_command=execv)

```
execl("/bin/touch", "touch", "filename", NULL);
          ^            ^         ^         ^
       command       command   argument    
        path           name
                     arg 0     arg 1
```

Answer (score 2):

Consider use system() instead:

```
system("/bin/ls -l > temporar.txt");
```

Or using execl call `/bin/sh` to redirect stream:

```
execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "-c" , "/bin/ls -l >temporar.txt", NULL);
```

First parameter of execl is a command to execute, second is a first parameter to be passed to command (argv[0]), third and next - other arguments argv[1] ...

Comment: I am not allowed to use system, i have to create myself the process, i don't want all the "ls -l", only to create the file

Comment: I get "No such file or directory" error when i run it like this "execl("/bin/sh", "/bin/sh", "/bin/>temporar.txt", NULL);" because i only want to create a file in the folder from where I am launching the c source, the ls-l was an example that worked and I've tried to adapt it to my problem

Comment: Sorry, forgot to pass -c flag